# Unable to get the "Add" method of a ColumnDefinitionCollection in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, com, uwp

In the context of a Windows Universal Application, and using reflection, I'm trying to get the `Add` method from a `ColumnDefinitionCollection` (the built-in type)

So I use this:

```
type.GetRuntimeMethods().First(info => info.Name == "Add");
```

**BUT it returns null!**

It also happens with the `Contains` method. Both of them are defined in `ICollection<T>` (`IList<T>` derives from it).

However, if I define my own class deriving from `IList<T>`, it works perfectly.

Then, how do I get a MethodInfo for the Add method? 
Is `ColumnDefinitionCollection` using some tricks? Maybe something related to COM?

Comment: Try `typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection).GetMethod(nameof(IList.Add), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);`. This should work. You probably don't find the method since it's implemented by `IList`. Reflection often flattens the search and thus restricts it to methods implemented by the class `ColumnDefinitionCollection`.

Comment: @SharpShade Unfortunately, my code runs on a Portable Class Library that doesn't have the method you mention :(

Comment: Okay, well. I haven't used PCLs yet, but I assume that what I said still applies. Reflection in UWP is a bit more restricted than in a normal .Net application that's why you can't find the method I mentioned. Nonetheless I guess that the internal system flattens the search which is why you don't see the Add method. *EDIT*: Okay, I erred. `GetRuntimeMethods` should also show inherited methods.

Comment: Try `typeof (ICollection<ColumnDefinition>).GetRuntimeMethods()`

Comment: I just tried it by myself. Well, seems to be an issue with the extension methods. If you do it like @YacoubMassad said, it works. By the way: There is also an extension method for `GetMethod` if you require so.

Comment: @YacoubMassad the bad thing is that I get this type in runtime, so all I can do is type.GetRuntimeMethods(

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307845/runtimereflectionextensions-getruntimemethod-does-not-work-as-expected) might be related.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I seems it's similar, but Add and Contains aren't extension methods, are part of IList<T>

Comment: You can get the implemented interfaces and search for methods there. Like this: `type.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.SelectMany(x => x.GetRuntimeMethods())`

Comment: @YacoubMassad COOL! It worked!! Could you please post it as an answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know why `GetRuntimeMethods` is not returning all methods. Is this the expected behavior? Or is it a bug?

Anyway, one solution (or probably a workaround) is to obtain the interfaces that the type implements and then get the methods of these interfaces like this:

```
var methodsOfImplementedInterfaces = 
    type
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .ImplementedInterfaces
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetRuntimeMethods())
        .ToList();
```

In your specific case, this will work because `Add` is actually defined on `ICollection<T>` which is implemented by `ColumnDefinitionCollection`.